# OutOfMemoryException when reading data from DataReader

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

This is the scenario: I'm making a TCP connection (to myself) to send some data in string format. I create a connection, I send the data and I immediately close the connection (I don't want to wait synchronously for data). Before sending the string, I append its length (`data.Length`) at the front of the string, so I know how much data to read when receiving it.
I've a `StreamSocketListener` listening for incoming data from TCP connections, and I made some "helper"-class to simplfy stuff for the outside world. The class is instantiated once, and the method `Start` is called to start listening for connections. That's the scenario.
When I send data (to myself, but this shouldn't matter) I get a `System.OutOfMemoryException` in the method `StreamReadLine`.

It's not very obvious to me why this happens, so this is why I'm here. I hope someone has dealt with this before and knows what the issue is.

```
public delegate void TCPRequestHandler(string data, string sender);
public class TCPSocketListener
{
    private int port;
    private StreamSocketListener listener;
    private bool mIsActive = false;
    private event TCPRequestHandler requestHandlerCallback;

    public bool isActive
    {
        get { return mIsActive; }
    }

    public TCPSocketListener(int port, TCPRequestHandler requestHandlerCallback)
    {
        this.port = port;
        this.requestHandlerCallback = requestHandlerCallback;
    }

    public async void Start()
    {
        if (!mIsActive)
        {
            mIsActive = true;
            listener = new StreamSocketListener();
            listener.Control.QualityOfService = SocketQualityOfService.Normal;
            listener.ConnectionReceived += Listener_ConnectionReceived;
            await listener.BindServiceNameAsync(port.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (mIsActive)
        {
            listener.Dispose();
            mIsActive = false;
        }
    }

    async void Listener_ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        string data = await ExtractRequestData(args.Socket);
        await Task.Run(() => requestHandlerCallback(data, args.Socket.Information.RemoteHostName.CanonicalName));
    }

    private async Task<string> ExtractRequestData(StreamSocket socket)
    {
        //Initialize IO classes
        DataReader reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
        //DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
        //writer.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;

        // get the data on the stream
        string data = await StreamReadLine(reader);

        socket.Dispose();
        return data;
    }

    private static async Task<string> StreamReadLine(DataReader reader)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("reading data");
        var stringHeader = await reader.LoadAsync(4);

        if (stringHeader == 0)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Header of the data was 0, for whatever reason");
            return "null";
        }
        int strLength = reader.ReadInt32();
        uint numStrBytes = await reader.LoadAsync((uint)strLength);
        string data = reader.ReadString(numStrBytes);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("read " + data);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code and verified that the value you get for `numStrBytes` is the correct value?

Comment: Eh. Silly me. It's not, the reported length is 892942715.. I'll have to find out why. Will report back later!

Comment: @HuRRaCaNe: That's "599{" in ascii/utf8. Possibly a length prefixed as a string instead of binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Lasse and Stephen (comments on question), because they were right. The data length was indeed first prefixed to the data, and then copied as bytes, instead of first getting the text as bytes, then prefixing the length as bytes.

So what I did was create a new byte array of the total length (the payload), then get the bytes of the data, and then fill up the first 4 bytes with the length of the data. Like so:

Before transfer:

```
// Add the length of the data at the start, so we know how much characters to read when receiving this
Int32 dataLength = data.Length;
// Add the data to be sent into the buffer
byte[] payload = new byte[sizeof(Int32) + (dataLength * sizeof(char))];
byte[] dataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(dataBytes, 0, payload, 4, dataBytes.Length);

payload[0] = (byte)(dataLength >> 24);
payload[1] = (byte)(dataLength >> 16);
payload[2] = (byte)(dataLength >> 8);
payload[3] = (byte)dataLength;
```

When receiving:

```
var stringHeader = await reader.LoadAsync(4);
Int32 strLength = reader.ReadInt32();
uint numStrBytes = await reader.LoadAsync((uint)strLength);
string data = reader.ReadString(numStrBytes);
```

Comment: You should look into [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) and [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: And I'm guessing you meant "Thanks to Lasse and Stephen" :) I may be somewhat of an odd fellow, but I sure ain't schizophrenic. And neither am I!